openpyxl - the write to and existing Excel file errors and deletes all the formulas
I have a large Excel xlsx file with 20 or more tabs. This simple piece of code creates a new woksheet and writes to it. On opening the file it reports errors and I find it has deleted all the formula in every worksheet.
The workbook has been fine up until now, it has been in existance for many months without any problems
Excel errors
"we found a problem with some content in TEST_FILE.xlsx Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can?
etc
Click "Yes"
"Excel was able to open the file by repairing or removing the unreadable content"
"Removed Feature: Named range from /xl/workbook.xml part (Workbook)"
The problem repeats after every attempt to run the code. The new worksheet is created and the test line "New Data 123456" written to it
# import openpyxl module 
import openpyxl 

path =  ('TEST_FILE.xlsx')

wb_obj_1 = openpyxl.load_workbook(path, data_only= True) 

sheet_1 = wb_obj_1['2024_Results'] 

sheet_2 = wb_obj_1.create_sheet("TEST", 0)

row = sheet_1.max_row 
column = sheet_1.max_column 

print(' ')
print("Total Rows:", row) 
print("Total Columns:", column) 

c = sheet_2['A7'] 
c.value = "New Data 123456"

wb_obj_1.save(path)


python 3.12.0
openpyxl v 3.1.2 (I have tried earlier versions with the same result)
Excel Version 2404 (Build 17531.20152)
Windows 10 Home 22H2 (OS build 19045.4412
As described above I expected the worksheet to be created and the data written to it. I did not expect the errors when the file was opened.
My question has no relationship whatsoever with this question My question is about the corruption of the excel file by the workbook.save.function and not about reading cells or formula.
From my comments below

"I have taken a known good copy of my file, with all the formulas
intact. A file that Excel hasn't had a problem with at all and still
doesn't The sample code above was modified to remove the lines to
create new sheet and write to a cell. The workbook was then saved as a
new name. "wb_obj_1.save('TEST_FILE4.xlsx')". Open the new file in
Excel and the same error and all the formulas gone. This is clearly a
problem with openpyxl Workbook.save()"


Openpyxl has the option of cell value being either the formula or value (set or calculated). If you open a workbook as data_only= True the cell.value will be the value and the formulas are not read. When saved the workbook will write the cell values, it doesn't have formulas to write. So if you write to the original workbook, it will overwrite the original with each cell being the value only.

Thanks, I had to use "data only" as the spreadsheet is full of formula to that populated the cells I wished to read and process with Python. Without "data only" python errored and the calculation I was trying to perform. So is there a work around to this situation?
How can I read values from cells that are formulas?
sheet_1.cell(row=1, column=1).value doesn't do it

I will also add that the spreadsheet is now devoid of any formulas and the error still exists on every run of the code

I don't see anything in your code that would cause a corruption of the workbook, so must be the workbook or its size. The usual workaround for unable to load large workbook is to load as read only but that negates writing your c.value if that's a requirement. Though you can write the whole or required parts to a new workbook. That method does at least protect your original workbook.

I should mention too, the data_only mode doesn't prevent you from writing formulas back to the sheet. Example if cell 'A10' had a formula '=SUM(A1:A9)' and your code updated the cell with that value then the cell will be that formula after saving.

The workbook started out at around  118KB is that large? It was 127KB but has shrunk with all the deletions. As I said the formula have now gone so not a complicated  workbook. But not 20 worksheets but around 40
Even so the error messages still occur when the code is run
My work around is to write the data out to another workbook

120kB is not particularly large but loading can depend on your computer capability and what data the Sheet(s) contain.

I have taken a known good copy of my file, with all the formulas intact. A file that Excel hasn't had a problem with at all and still doesn't
The sample code above was modified to remove the lines to create new sheet and write to a cell. The workbook was then saved as a new name. "wb_obj_1.save('TEST_FILE4.xlsx')". Open the new file in Excel and the same error and all the formulas gone. This is clearly a problem with openpyxl Workbook.save()

FYI @Charlie Clark
